# How to find out what particular vector component is animated?

Tags: python

I can iterate over animation f-curves of an object and identify animated properties through `data_path` attribute:

```
o = bpy.data.objects['myObj']
fcurves = o.animation_data.action.fcurves
for fc in fcurves:
    print(fc.data_path)
```

I also need to distinguish between different vector components for properties like 'rotation_euler'. When all 3 of them are animated they can be identified by their relative order, but I can't find a way to identify individual components when only 1 or 2 of them are animated. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector components are accessible through the `fc.array_index` value. If you only animate the X and Z components, you'll see that they are still indices 0 and 2, not 0 and 1.